Deathtrap involving a punctured flour sack eventually knocking a lamp into an open gas stove to cause an explosion
This is one of those things that has bugged me for years, but I've never been able to quite track it down. My mother, who enjoyed crime TV shows, was watching one in the United States (likely Kentucky, either Louisville or Ashland) when I was probably in elementary school (so somewhere between 1985 and 1991), probably on public network TV (we didn't get cable for a long time). There's a scene where a man is tied up (I think to a chair) while another man sets up a deathtrap involving a punctured flour sack (my memory is of a paper sack which was punctured with a switchblade knife) that was set up so that it would fall and either pull over or knock over a lamp with an exposed incandescent bulb, causing it to fall into an open oven. I remember it as having worked despite the victim's attempts to work free of their bindings and escape. I do not remember if it showed the explosion in the room, cut to the outside with the explosion, or merely indicated via something like a media report that the explosion had occurred.
As a child, I understood this to be a matter of that the combination of lightbulbs and ovens was extremely incendiary. It was years later that I realized that it was almost certainly a gas oven and that the exposed sparking filaments would set off an explosion. Because of my rather scant memory of details (I don't know for certain if it was an episode of a TV show or a film that was being shown on TV), and the common nature of the items, I have not been able to track this down, so I figured I would put it to Stack Exchange and see if someone else remembers this scene. Thank you.
